# chef service[auditd] is broken for centos-7

Tags: chef-infra, centos7

I am attempting to run the service resource on a centos7 ec2 instance (ami-d2c924b2) for auditd:

```
 service 'auditd' do
   provider Chef::Provider::Service::Init::Redhat
   action :nothing
 end
```

However it seems that the service resource is broken for centos7 instances:

```
service[auditd]: unable to locate the init.d script!
```

I am also getting this error: `service[auditd] cannot be found in the resource collection.`

Answer (score 2):

The `Redhat` provider is specifically for the redhat flavor of `/etc/init.d` management. CentOS 7 uses systemd instead, which should be auto detected.